# Why should we use pointer-to-arrays in C/C++?

Tags: c, pointer-to-array

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define SIZE 3

int main()
{   
    char intArrayOne[SIZE] = {'A', 'B', 'C'};

    char (*ptrToAnOneDimArray)[SIZE] = &intArrayOne;

    int i = 0;
    for(i=0 ; i<SIZE ; i++)
    {
        printf("%c ", (*ptrToAnOneDimArray)[i]);
    }
}

Output
A B C
```

When should we use "ptrToAnOneDimArray" - kinds of usages in C/C++? Please give me a real-world example.

Can we avoid these kinds of complex and fuzzy usages of pointers?

Comment: "Need" is such a funny word.  I can't think of when I last might have used one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, when you want to implement a dynamic multidimensional array:

```
int (*ptrArr)[WIDTH] = malloc(sizeof ptrArr[0] * HEIGHT);
```

is **much better** than

```
int **ptrPtr = malloc(sizeof ptrPtr[0] * HEIGHT);
for (size_t i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
    ptrPtr[i] = malloc(sizeof ptrPtr[0][i] * WIDTH);
}
```

for various reasons (it **does actually** point to a 2D array that is **contiguous in memory**, it requires less allocations and frees, so it's less likely that you get it wrong, etc.)

Comment: While it is true, I think that it is better to wrap the array in a struct to make for clearer code.

Comment: @C.R. No. Or it's *at most* a stylistic preference, but it certainly doesn't "clear" the code. An array should be an array, and not a struct.

Comment: An array inside a struct (a poor man's `std::array`) behaves very much like an array, but more semantically clear.

Comment: @C.R. Citation needed. (oh, and this is not C++ but C.)

Comment: It is just personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you are embedded programmer. Now you have some piece of hardware with exchangable modules. With each module you must communicate differently ie. you init/read/write to/from it differently.

Now you have your software that must handle all of these module types. You have 3 routines (simplified here) to init, read, write each type module (HW0 is module A, HW1 is module B).

```
void HW0_init() { printf("HW0_init\n"); }
void HW0_read() { printf("HW0_read\n"); }
void HW0_write(){ printf("HW0_write\n"); }

void HW1_init() { printf("HW1_init\n"); }
void HW1_read() { printf("HW1_read\n"); }
void HW1_write(){ printf("HW1_write\n"); }
```

Now imagine you want to init your module and read sth from it so you do:

```
int hw_id = 1;

// want to init hardware
switch(hw_id)
{
    case 0: HW0_init(); break;
    case 1: HW1_init(); break;
    // ...
}

// now I want to read
switch(hw_id)
{
    case 0: HW0_read(); break;
    case 1: HW1_read(); break;
    // ...
}
```

This may be accomplished differently using pointers to arrays. If you declare arrays of pointers to your functions like so:

```
// as many arrays as you have modules
void (*hw0[3])() = { HW0_init, HW0_read, HW0_write };
void (*hw1[3])() = { HW1_init, HW1_read, HW1_write };
```

your code may be simplified to this:

```
enum HW_ACTION
{
    HW_INIT = 0,
    HW_READ = 1,
    HW_WRITE = 2
};

// pointer to array of pointers to funcs taking nothing
// and returning nothing
void (*(*f)[3])(void);

// detect hardware and set 'f'
f = &hw1;

(*f)[HW_INIT](); // same as HW1_init(); <=> hw1[HW_INIT]();
(*f)[HW_READ](); // same as HW1_read(); <=> hw1[HW_READ]();
```

Same effect - 'easier code'.

You may treat it as `poor's man virtual methods` for C users having no C++ compiler where you would normally create base abstract class with `init`, `read`, `write` methods and implement them for every kind of module.

Real life here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table.

Answer (score -1):

Pointers-to-pointers (hence pointers-to-arrays by proxy) are really useful. If you have a function/method and it takes a pointer-to-value argument you can change the value inside your function and that value stays in scope after you leave the function - pass-by-reference of course. However you can't change the address your pointer points at - e.g. make the pointer you passed into a NULL pointer, or point it at a different value somewhere else in memory. If you use a pointer-to-pointer-to-value then you can change the value of the 'middle' pointer inside your function. I think the MySQL C-connector library is an example of where this is used.

In your example you could pass `ptrToAnOneDimArray` into a function and make *ptrToAnOneDimArray be a NULL pointer or a pointer to some other data rather than `intArrayOne` - as `intArrayOne` is a fixed size by the compiler (on the stack) then you could dynamically update *ptrToAnOneDimArray from the stack to be an array malloc()'d on the heap.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 3

void display(char* data) {
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0 ; i<SIZE ; i++) {
        printf("%c ", data[i]);
    }
}

void changeMyArgument(char** pointerToPointer) {

    *pointerToPointer = (char*) malloc(SIZE * sizeof(char));

    /* now we use array notation for a change */
    (*pointerToPointer)[0] = 'X';
    (*pointerToPointer)[1] = 'Y';
    (*pointerToPointer)[2] = 'Z';
}

int main() {

    /* intArrayOne is implicitly char* */
    char intArrayOne[SIZE] = {'A', 'B', 'C'};
    char* arraysArePointers = intArrayOne;   

    /* ptrToAnOneDimArray is implicitly char** */
    char** ptrToAnOneDimArray;
    ptrToAnOneDimArray = &arraysArePointers;

    display(*ptrToAnOneDimArray);

    changeMyArgument(ptrToAnOneDimArray);

    display(*ptrToAnOneDimArray);

}
```

Comment: `you can't change the address your pointer points at` - that's curious

Comment: @Artur not if you pass the pointer *by value* into a function.

Comment: Question is about pointers-to-arrays, not pointers-to-pointers. Pointers and arrays are different things.

Comment: @newacct Have you heard the term 'pointer and array equivalence' http://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_59.htm. NB edit they are not *very* different things they are *almost the same* thing

Comment: @abasterfield: No they are not. They are completely different types. An array expression can just be *converted into* a pointer expression in some contexts. Anyway, there is no "pointer" to "point to" here at all. What is pointed to is an *array*.

Comment: An array expression can be converted into a pointer expression *and vice versa*, in my example I use malloc() followed by array subscript access to set values. Infact the only practical difference where arrays and pointer cannot be used interchangeably is that sizeof a pointer will give you pointer size wheras sizeof an array declared statically or on the stack will give you the length of the allocation. Are you saying pointer array equivalence isn't a thing? Please clarify your position.